# capture image using android's camera application

Tags: android, camera, image-capture

Is it possible to write code which not only invokes the `default camera` application in android but also captures the image (automatically, not with `user pressing the capture button`).

With the help of [photobasics](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) tutorial, I want to access built-in camera from my application, but how can I also automatically capture the image once the app opens?

I know this can be done via camera api, but is there anyway to `trigger the capture` function of `mobile's camera app`?

Comment: use camera api and can create cousam camera and also see takepickure() run 1 by 1

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it using Camera Api.

[Camera API in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html)

[API](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCamera/article.html)

No need to do any UI for capturing then Image just call the camera api using service or any background thread or as you want.